# R split uneven strings with uneven number of spaces

Tags: r

I'm trying to split uneven strings with multiple spaces. However the number of spaces to be split is not always the same number, e.g.

```
 "abc          20"
 "csd   10"
 "eds     10     30"
```

and I'm trying to obtain the following:

```
"abc" " " "20"
"csd" "10" " "
"eds" "10" "30"
```

Any idea how to do this? Note that splitting based on a fixed number of spaces is not possible as these vary a bit. I was thinking about splitting on exactly one space either led by or followed by a character or a number, however I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Why does the first one have a space in the middle and the second one have a space at the end?

Comment: That's how the final data should look like... three variables. The strings contain spaces when for the second variable no data is recorded, whereas for for the third variable the string is just chopped off.

Comment: But how do you know? Both the first and second line look like `"<letters> <spaces> <letters>"`, and you say the number of spaces varies, so how do you know that they get different results? How do you know the second row isn't "chopped off" like the first row? If you can explain a logic to that, then we can code it.

Comment: Well because the strings are read from a pdf and I can visually see which figure belongs to which column.

Comment: Are the lengths of the three variables always the same? That is, when the string is split, will the first always be three? Will the second and third always be two?

Comment: Additionally, is it possible to identify a set number of spaces which are given? X for only first and last vars filled, Y for first and second filled, and Z for all three filled? Where in your example above X=10, Y=4, Z=5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) read.fwf** Try `read.fwf`.  Adjust the widths as needed.

```
s <- c("abc          20", "csd   10", "eds     10     30")  # test data
read.fwf(textConnection(s), widths = c(3, 7, 7))
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2 V3
1 abc NA 20
2 csd 10 NA
3 eds 10 30
```

**2) kmeans**  This approach finds the starting columns, `g`, of fields 2 and 3 and clusters them into two groups using `kmeans`.  It assumes that field 1 is always present since that seems to be the case in the question.  Then if there are two fields on a line it assigns the second field to the group center that it is closest to.

```
km <- kmeans(unlist(gregexpr(" \\S", s)), 2)
centers <- sort(km$centers)
g <- gregexpr(" \\S", s)
spl <- strsplit(s, " +")
f <- function(s, g) {
  if (length(s) == 2) paste0(s[1], strrep(",", which.min(abs(g - centers))), s[2])
  else paste(s, collapse = ",")
}
read.table(text = mapply(f, spl, g), sep = ",", fill = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2 V3
1 abc NA 20
2 csd 10 NA
3 eds 10 30
```

Comment: Almost there, but in the first row the 20 should be in V3 with V2 being NA... Can't do it manually, too many rows.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is splitting on a fixed number of characters. Manually adjusting the widths will take too much time as the other rows are slightly different and way too many...

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but I do not obtain the same... basically I get: "    abc X20 X50" "csd 10 60 NA" "eds 10 30 40"

Comment: Hmm seems like it only works with Rstudio and not with standard R. Nevertheless, great solution!

Comment: I am using standard R on Windows and it works for me.  I also tried it on Linux Ubuntu and it worked there too.  Restart R and try it again. If you still have a problem then start R with `R --vanilla` or on Windows `Rgui --vanilla`

Answer (score 0):

I got another solution that saves the labor of counting the spaces :>

```
s_split = data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    s= df[i,1]
    new_list = stringr::str_split_1(s,' ')
    temp = as.data.frame(t(new_list[new_list !='']))
    s_split= dplyr::bind_rows(s_split, temp )
} 
s_split
```

Here is the toy data based on the posts above:

```
a = "abc          20"
b = "csd   10"
c =  "eds     10     30"
df = as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))
```